# Why are javascript files from angular project not being identified as javascript?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular7

I have been working integrating an Angular 7 project into a ASP.NET Core MVC project but have recently run into an issue. When testing the solution, I ran into a problem in which Edge gave a HTTP 404 error. When tested on Firefox, the Javascript console gave a warning messaged that read `Javascript files are being identified as HTML files`.
The only actions I have taken are to build the Angular project, copy the Angular project into a subfolder in the ASP.NET Core project, then adding the built files to a razor file. The razor file:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<h1>This is the Index page</h1>
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/frontend/runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/frontend/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/frontend/styles.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/frontend/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="~/ClientApp/dist/frontend/main.js"></script>
}
```

Can someone explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you put them into wwwroot folder?

Comment: Why dont use build in template of Angular and ASP.Net Core in visual studio ?

Comment: @TonyNgo The Angular template for ASP.NET Core does not (as of writing) include Angular 7 or 8, I am currently using Angular 7. The template mainly uses Angular 6. In addition, I am wanting to use Angular within razor pages, something which the template does not make clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to have an access to a folder outside the `wwwroot`, assume `ClientApp` foler ,you need to configure `app.UseStaticFiles()` in startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ClientApp")),
    RequestPath = "/ClientApp",
    EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
});
}
```

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#usefileserver

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to [write rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) on your web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="angular-application" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="angular-application/(.*)" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="ClientApp/dist/frontend/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
<configuration>
```

and then import like this:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script src="angular-application/runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-application/polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-application/styles.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-application/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-application/main.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: @Boolean asp.net core does use webconfig. It's just use default webconfig when you deploy your web app to server. So to override webconfig from the hosting you can create your own webconfig